# Reload Object after save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using [mongodb](http://mongodb.org/) and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). Some of the properties of the document schema that I use have defaults which are set when the document is saved. I intend to read these properties after calling the `save()` function of a document instance. However, the `save()` does not seem to apply the change to the document instance:

```
doc.save();
console.log(doc.somePropertySetByDefault); // undefined
```

Is there a way how one can do that without writing an entire query (i.e. `Doc.findOne(...)`)?

Comment: Is it only the property that's coming back undefined? or is it the doc itself?

Comment: It is only the property.

Comment: And what is the result when you explicitly set the property before the save?

Comment: The idea is precisely not to set the property explicitly for reasons of consistency and separation of concerns. :-)

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question: properties that are explicitly set can be read after a call to `save()`.

Comment: I understand. Just troubleshooting. Glad you've solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to call `doc.populate()`.